# shell_exec hosting service with wget, ping, curl, shell

Tags: linux, shell, hosting, web-hosting, shell-exec

Maybe this is not right place, but I doesn't know where I can post this topic. Sorry for that, but maybe somebody can help me.

I need web hosting service on Linux server.
I need to run shell_exec scripts like wgetm ping, curl etc.
Example, I want make php script for download, ping and show result.

The most hosting services dones't allow to use this commands for security reasons. I understand this, but **is anybody know any hosting service with this features?** 
Thanks

Comment: WebHostingTalk.com is the place to ask about hosting.  This site is for programming questions.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has a list of other SE sites that you can look through to find one appropriate for your question.